# meta_query for a string inside a meta field containing a comma-separated list

Tags: custom-field, meta-query, user-meta

In my project the WP users have a custom meta field "usergroup" containing a comma separated list of values. The meta field can contain values like this:

```
WS,CT,IS,TS,TS-IS,TS-WS,TS-CT
```

Now I would like to create a meta_query() that returns all users that have for example the value "IS" in this field. I can achieve this with this code:

```
    $args = array(
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'usergroup',
                'value' => 'IS'
                'compare'   => 'IN'
            )
        )
    );
    $users = get_users($args);
```

But compare => IN matches for all occurences of "IS", so also for "TS-IS", which is not desired.

Is there a smart way to meta_query so it matches just "IS, but not "TS-IS"?

Comment: This is actually more of a generic SQL question, but yes, you would want to use `REGEXP` as the `compare` value and then set the `value` to something like `(^|,)IS(,|$)`. And be sure to properly escape the `IS` or whatever is the actual value.

Comment: Interesting, will it work with with comma before value `'value' => ',IS'` ?

Comment: Yes. Sally's regular expression accounts for `IS` bounded on the left by either the start of the string or a comma and bounded on the right by either a comma or the end of the string. There are a number of sites available to experiment with and help interpret regular expressions - I like https://regex101.com

Comment: @Sally CJ: Thanks for the answer, I tried your solution but strangely it doesnt return results, although regex101.com shows your regex is correct. This is my updated code:

` 'meta_query' => array(
      array(
         'key'          => 'usergroup',
         'value'        => '(^|,)IS(,|$)',
         'compare'      => 'REGEXP'
      )
  )
`

But it returns NULL, although there should be results. Is the format incorrect?

Comment: @Nicolai, that looks good to me. So are you sure *in the database*, the meta value is indeed a comma-separated list like `CT,IS`? Try `SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'usergroup' LIMIT 5` on phpMyAdmin or a similar tool, and just check the meta values. (Change the table prefix if it's not `wp_`) And how did you add the meta field; using a plugin?

Comment: @SallyCJ: Sorry for the late reply. Your guess was right, a check in the databse revealed that the values are actually stored serialized, like this:

`a:11:{i:0;s:2:"IS";i:1;s:5:"TS-IS";i:2;s:6:"TS-USA";i:3;s:2:"TS";i:4;s:3:"EKG";i:5;s:2:"WS";i:6;s:2:"CT";i:7;s:6:"TS-MAX";i:8;s:5:"TS-XD";i:9;s:6:"TS-CTM";i:10;s:5:"TS-MT";}`

The meta field is added using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. I guess REGEXP is not useful for my case then. Still the original question and your solution to it is very useful in my opinion, just not for my specific case it seems.

Comment: You could still use `REGEXP` because regular expression is powerful.. however, you would just use `LIKE` with `"<value>"` as the value (e.g. `'value' => '"IS"'`) as suggested in my answer. Check it out and let me know. :)

Comment: I wonder how is this code working for you, since I also have a comma-separated meta field and the 'IN' compare isn't working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a smart way to meta_query so it matches just "IS, but not
> "TS-IS"?

The WordPress meta query [class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/) (`WP_Meta_Query`), which among others, is used with the posts (`WP_Query`) and users (`WP_User_Query`) query classes, supports [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) (since WordPress 3.7) as the `compare` value, so you could use that with a RegEx (regular expresion) pattern like `(^|,)IS(,|$)`, like so:

```php
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'usergroup',
        'compare' => 'REGEXP',
        // With dynamic values, be sure to properly escape the "IS" or whatever
        // is the actual value. E.g. '(^|,)' . preg_quote( $value ) . '(,|$)'
        'value'   => '(^|,)IS(,|$)',
    ),
),
```

So that should work well for meta values that *in the database* are stored in the form of a comma-separated list, i.e. `value, value, value, ...` (with or without the whitespaces), and you can test the above pattern [here](https://regex101.com/r/MM5wO8/1).

However, since you said (in the comments) that the meta values are actually serialized like so:

```
a:11:{i:0;s:2:"IS";i:1;s:5:"TS-IS";i:2;s:6:"TS-USA";i:3;s:2:"TS";i:4;s:3:"EKG";i:5;s:2:"WS";i:6;s:2:"CT";i:7;s:6:"TS-MAX";i:8;s:5:"TS-XD";i:9;s:6:"TS-CTM";i:10;s:5:"TS-MT";}
```

Then you would instead want to use `LIKE` as the `compare` value, but use `"<value>"` as the `value`'s value like this:

```php
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'usergroup',
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
        // With dynamic values, be sure to properly escape the "IS" or whatever
        // is the actual value.
        'value'   => '"IS"',
    ),
),
```

Try a [demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qnEbghWVeSbkxbifvfi4Qb/1).